# Search within list of objects in mongodb using morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am very new to Java. I am very new to mongoDB.

I have a collection that looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "1234",
    "name" : "bill",
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "fooType" : "bar",
            .....
        },
        {
            "fooType" : "oof",
            .....
        }        
    ],
    "status" : "Truncated"
},
{...}
```

I am trying to implement a search feature to search by fooType. I am able to create a working query using standard mongodb syntax, but cannot figure out how to implement using morphia.

A working mongodb query :

```
db.Clients.find({products: {$elemMatch: {fooType: "bar"}}})
```

Some (truncated) code that I've tried without any success:

```
DatastoreImpl ds;
q = ds.createQuery(Clients.class).field("products").hasThisElement("fooType");
```

Obviously this doesn't work because it expects an object. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to use hasThisElement, and I'm not even sure if that's the best way to go about this anymore.

Comment: Did you try `ds.createQuery(Clients.class).field("products.fooType").hasThisElement("bar")`?

Comment: Same error: `invalid parameter: expected an object ($elemMatch)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hasThisElement` expects an object in the parameter, so you couldn't use a String "fooType" or “bar”.

Assume that you have the following classes for this collection:

```
class Clients {
String id;
String name;
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
String status;
}

class Product {
String fooType;
....
}
```

To use `$elemMatch`, you would need to create an object for the filter on `products` as below, and use this filter object in `hasThisElement()`:

```
Product filterProduct = new Product();
filterProduct.fooType = "bar";
Query q = ds.createQuery(Clients.class).field("products").hasThisElement(filterProduct);
```

Comment: I had originally marked this correct, but I'm not sure now. I want to be able to search by fooType. This seems that I would need to have an exact match for the object I'm looking for, rather than finding all objects that have fooType="bar", correct?

Comment: You don't need to use the $elemMatch operator unless you want to match more than one component within an array element.

Comment: This query ds.createQuery(Clients.class).field("products").hasThisElement(filterProduct) will be interpreted to: { "products" : { "$elemMatch" : { "fooType" : "bar"}}}. If you just want to return all the documents that have "fooType":"bar" in field products, you can just use the query db.Clients.find({"products.fooType":"bar"}), and the corresponding code in morphia is: ds.createQuery(Clients.class).filter("products.fooType","bar");